# I am getting ERROR "no response on Sdout" on Python Hackerrank

Tags: python

I am getting "no response on stdout"
again and again please help

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):

if __name__ == '__main__':
    meal_cost = float(input())

    tip_percent = int(input())

    tax_percent = int(input())

    tip = meal_cost*(0.2)
    tax = meal_cost*(.08)
    totalCost = meal_cost + tip + tax
    round(totalCost)
    print(totalCost)

    solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)
```

Comment: Did you forget to put `solve` function ?

Comment: The code is not correct - it will produce an error.  If your intention is to learn how to code, I suggest you to run it in regular python in your PC (or an emulator online), and try and understand the error and then try to solve it by yourself. 
Hackerrank may not give you meaningful error messages, so it would be really hard for you to find the problem that way.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you put the code for the `solve` function in the wrong place. Try this:

```
def solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent):
    tip = meal_cost*(0.2)
    tax = meal_cost*(.08)
    totalCost = meal_cost + tip + tax
    round(totalCost)
    print(totalCost)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    meal_cost = float(input())
    tip_percent = int(input())
    tax_percent = int(input())

    solve(meal_cost, tip_percent, tax_percent)
```

Comment: Glad I could help you. If my answer was helpful, consider marking it accepted with the big check mark :)